# Create new table using last row of other table in power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

I have following table **AllIterationTable**

| AreaPath | IterationPath | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| power | power - Sprint1 | 08-03-2021 00:00 | 13-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - Sprint 3 | 15-03-2021 00:00 | 20-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - Migration | 22-03-2021 00:00 | 27-03-2021 00:00 |
| power | power - License | 29-03-2021 00:00 | 03-04-2021 00:00 |

I want to get whole row based on latest date of `StartDate` column.
I expect output, LastRowTable,

| AreaPath | IterationPath | StartDate | EndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| power | power - License | 29-03-2021 00:00 | 03-04-2021 00:00 |

Comment: Did you try using MAX(StartDate), and simply taking that row?

Comment: I know I can use MAX function to get latest row but I don't know how to create table on that formula.

Comment: We can use formula and create new column or measure in same table. But I already have so many columns (there is many columns I want lasted value) so I don't want to create Burdon on same table. So best solution is get lasted row and create new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the calculated table as follows:

```
MyTable=
VAR maxDate = CALCULATE( MAX( AllIterationTable[StartDate] ), ALL( AllIterationTable ) )
VAR result =
FILTER( 
   AllIterationTable, 
   AllIterationTable[StartDate] = maxDate
)
RETURN
   result
```